# The condition in while loop is broken (Now with a snippet)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Le'ts make it clear, the condition in the while loop has to check if the new challenge's number hasn't done yet (as seen in the challenges.finished array)
Which means the same challenge can be shown few times instead of only one time (as needed) if you notice any mistake in the code, please let me know.

```js
var challenges = {
        names: [],
        info: [],
        mascot: [],
        now: [],
        finished: []
    };
challenges.names = ['',
                  'The Best Mess', //1
                  'Pookie Madness', //2
                  'A Cookie for Rookie', //3
                  'Water Party!', //4
                  'You took my hair?!', //5
                  'Too. Much. Pizza.', //6
                  'Love is All', //7
                 'Mop the Deck', //8
                 'Be ya Piate', //9
                 'Treasure Hunter', //10
                 'Spread the Love', //11
                 'You are Arrested!', //12
                 'DINO Four', //13
                 "Viking's Moment", //14
                 "Let me Fly!", //15
                 'Do it Smart', //16
                 'Just a Luck', //17
                 'Sporty', //18
                 'Adopt my Emoji', //19
                 "Hey, it's me!", //20
                 'Me and the Music', //21
                 'Puffle Combo', //22
                 'Richest Pirate', //23
                 'Just Chill', //24
                 'You are BANNED', //25
                 'Merry Walrus', //26
                 'Goo Red!!!', //27
                 'Goo Blue!!!', //28
                 'Oops I did it again', //29
                 "Summer's love", //30
                 'Follow da Arrows', //31
                 'I Call it Magic', //32
                 'Welcome to CPI!', //33
                 'Color Changer', //34
                 'Time to Mine!', //35
                 "Parties' Enemy", //36
                 'Dab on them', //37
                 'Paint Wall', //38
                 'Foody Hunter', //39
                 'Squid ya Say?', //40
                 'May the Force', //41
                 'Mustache Forever', //42
                 'Smart Match', //43
                 'Effects Expert', //44
                 'My Name Jeff', //45
                 'SPOOOOKY', //46
                 'WANTED'], //47
    challenges.info = ['',
                      'Change your hair 2 times', //1
                      'Wear a crown and a teddy bear', //2
                      'Put on a cookie', //3
                      'Put a watery background', //4
                      "Put on Rookie's wig", //5
                      "Eat a pizza while on the stadium", //6
                      "Change to a lovely background", //7
                      "Put on a mop at the Migrator", //8
                      "Wear at least one pirate-y item", //9
                      "Find a treasure!", //10
                      "Put a heart near your emoji", //11
                      "Put on a police hat", //12
                      "Use a dino face", //13
                      "Wear a viking helmet", //14
                      "Change to a clouds background", //15
                      "Remove an item/s using the button", //16
                      "Generate a random item/s", //17
                      "Pick any ball", //18
                      "Go to the Pet Shop", //19
                      'Use the "It\'s Me" background', //20
                      'Put on headphones', //21
                      'Adopt a puffle', //22
                      'Use the most expensive item', //23
                      'Put on Blizzard Beach glasses', //24
                      "Hold Thor's Hammer", //25
                      "Merry Walrus!", //26
                      'Cheer the red team', //27
                      'Cheer the blue team', //28
                      'Use the fart speech bubble', //29
                      'Pick the lovely sun', //30
                      'Pick the map', //31
                      'Pick any potion', //32
                      'Put the "Welcome CPI" background', //33
                      "Change your emoji's color", //34
                      "Put a hard hat", //35
                      "Pop the balloons", //36
                      "Dabs dabs dabs dabs", //37
                      "Pick a spray can and bricks", //38
                      'Pick 3 different CPI food', //39
                      'Pick a squid stick', //40
                      'Pick a lightsaber', //41
                      'Put on a mustache', //42
                      'Put hair and a head item', //43
                      'Add 3 effects to your emoji', //44
                      'Name your emoji Jeff', //45
                      'Wear at least 1 Halloween item', //46
                      'Go to the jail'], //47
    challenges.mascot = ['',
                           'R', //1
                           'R', //2
                           'R', //3
                           'R', //4
                           'R', //5
                           'R', //6
                           'AA', //7
                           'RH', //8
                           'RH', //9
                           'RH', //10
                           'AA', //11
                           'AA', //12
                           'AA', //13
                           'RH', //14
                           'R', //15
                           'AA', //16
                           'RH', //17
                           'AA', //18
                           'RH', //19
                           'R', //20
                           'R', //21
                           'AA', //22
                           'RH', //23
                           'R', //24
                           'AA', //25
                           'R', //26
                           'R', //27
                           'R', //28
                           'RH', //29
                           'AA', //30
                           'RH', //31
                           'RH', //32
                           'RH', //33
                           'AA', //34
                           'RH', //35
                           'R', //36
                           'R', //37
                           'R', //38
                           'RH', //39
                           'RH', //40
                           'RH', //41
                           'AA', //42
                           'AA', //43
                           'AA', //44
                           'R', //45
                           'RH', //46
                           'RH'], //47
    challenges.now = ['', -1, -1, -1],
    challenges.finished = [],
    total = 0;
var random_number, this_id2;

function addChallenge(i) {
    $('.all_daily_challenges').append('<div class=CPI_challenge' + i + 'o' + challenges.now[i] + ' alt=o' + challenges.mascot[challenges.now[i]] + '> </div>');
    var where_to_add = $('.CPI_challenge' + i + 'o' + challenges.now[i]);
    where_to_add.append('<div id=phone_challenge' + i + 'o' + challenges.now[i] + '_symbol_' + challenges.mascot[challenges.now[i]] + '> </div>');
    where_to_add.append('<div id=Challenge_name' + i + 'o' + challenges.now[i] + '>' + challenges.names[challenges.now[i]] + '</div>');
    where_to_add.append('<div id=Challenge_info' + i + 'o' + challenges.now[i] + '>' + challenges.info[challenges.now[i]] + '</div>');
    where_to_add.append('<div id=challenge_progress' + i + 'o' + challenges.now[i] + '>Collect</div>');
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * challenges.names.length) + 1);
    while ($.inArray(random_number, challenges.now) != -1) {
        random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * challenges.names.length) + 1);
    }
    challenges.now[i] = random_number;
    addChallenge(i)
}

$(document).on('click', '[id^=challenge_progress]', function () {
    this_id = $(this).attr('id');
    this_id = parseInt(this_id.substr(18, 19));
    challenges.finished.push(challenges.now[this_id]);
    random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * challenges.names.length) + 1);
    while ($.inArray(random_number, challenges.now) != -1 && $.inArray(random_number, challenges.finished) != -1) {
        random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * challenges.names.length) + 1);
    }
    $('.CPI_challenge' + this_id + 'o' + challenges.now[this_id]).remove()
    challenges.now[this_id] = random_number;
    addChallenge(this_id)
    alert(challenges.finished)
})
```

```css
.phone_black_screen {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 6;
}

.CPI_phone {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(#3DB8B6, #abd99b);
}

#cpi_phone_title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fbf7f7;
    color: #548C02;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Loyola';
    line-height: 10vh;
    z-index: 5;
}

#CPI_phone_shadow1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 11%;
    left: 5px;
    width: 15%;
    height: 5%;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#CPI_phone_shadow2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 11%;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    max-width: 500px;
    content: url('Navigation/shadow1.png')
}

#CPI_phone_shadow3 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 11%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 10%;
    height: 15%;
    width: 35%;
    max-width: 500px;
    content: url('Navigation/shadow2.png');
    z-index: 10;
}

.CPI_apps {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 35%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 500px;
    background: none;
}

[id^=CPI_app] {
    margin: auto;
}

#exit_phone {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 5vw;
    height: 5.5vw;
    min-width: 30px;
    min-height: 35px;
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 55px;
    content: url(Navigation/exit_phone.png);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10;
}

.CPI_phone_white2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 11%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fbf7f7;
    color: #548C02;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Loyola';
    line-height: 10vh;
    z-index: 6;
    box-shadow: 0 -4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#CPI_phone_white2_shadow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    max-width: 400px;
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.all_daily_challenges {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 25%;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 98%;
    height: 40%;
    max-height: 300px;
    max-width: 1000px;
    background: #044F63;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 6;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

[class^=CPI_challenge] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    z-index: 6;
    max-width: 350px;
}

[id^=Challenge_info] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1vh;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

[id^=phone_challenge] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -30px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 20vw;
    max-width: 80px;
    height: auto;
}

[id*=symbol_AA] {
    content: url('Phone_Challenges/AuntArctic_PC.png');
}

[id*=symbol_R] {
    content: url('Phone_Challenges/Rookie_PC.png');
    width: 15vw;
    max-width: 65px;
}

[id*=symbol_RH] {
    content: url('Phone_Challenges/Rockhopper_PC.png');
    width: 20vw;
    max-width: 85px;
}


[id^=Challenge_name] {
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 70%;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 7;
    font-family: 'Loyola';
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#name_CPI_challenge {
    position: absolute;
    height: 10%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 70%;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index: 7;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Loyola';
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

[class^=CPI_challenge1] {
    left: 0%;
}

[class^=CPI_challenge2] {
    left: 95%;
}

[class^=CPI_challenge3] {
    left: 175%;
}

[id^=challenge_progress] {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    max-width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #3db8b6;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 0 #2F918F;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Loyola';
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

[id^=challenge_progress]:hover {
    transform: translateY(2px);
    background: #2F918F;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 0 #266F6D;
}

[alt=oR] {
    background: #EEED9A;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #C4D181;
    color: #E6984D;
    font-family: 'Rookie';
}

[alt=oAA] {
    background: #FBF9F6;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #5FBA15;
    color: #3F661B;
    font-family: 'Aunt Arctic';
}

[alt=oRH] {
    background: #ECBA67;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #C26241;
    color: #AD6C2F;
    font-family: 'Rockhopper';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='phone_black_screen'>
  <div class='CPI_phone_white'>
    <div id='cpi_phone_title'>
        Emoji Maker Phone
    </div>
    <div id='exit_phone'> </div>
    <div class='CPI_phone'>
        <div id='CPI_phone_shadow1'></div>
        <div id='CPI_phone_shadow2'></div>
        <div id='CPI_phone_shadow3'></div>
    </div>
    <div id='name_CPI_challenge'> Daily Challenges </div>
    <div class='all_daily_challenges'>
    </div>
    <table class='CPI_apps'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id='CPI_app1'></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class='CPI_phone_white2'>
        <div id='CPI_phone_white2_shadow'></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: Your using ID's as selectors, may I suggest using a class or custom data-attribute's.  ID's are meant to be unique per page.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the ID's are unique in this case...

Comment: You able to make your code into a working Snippet,..  It will make it a lot easier for people to help.

Comment: Your post had a working snippet, you have now gone back.. Any reason?..  Also the way your doing this is not pretty,.. Doing delegated events on a changing selector like this might not be possible. But if you used a data-attribute you could do a selector like   `$('[data-id]')`  and that's it, no manually creating a custom ID made up of appending this and that.

Comment: There was a problem on the snip that the challenges didn't show, otherwise, can you please clear your answer?

Comment: All your snippet was missing was the jQuery part.  I added that, and your snippet worked fine, showing the problem.  Images of course were not working, but it was working enough so people could run and see the issue.  Your two Pre blocks are pretty useless compared to a snippet.  But it's up to you, I'm sure you will get more help having a semi-working Snippet, rather than blocks of un-runnable code.

Comment: `can you please clear your answer`,,  what do you mean?

Comment: with the deta-id selector, and how can it help me in someway

Comment: If you use a `[data-id]` selector, you can get the id on your click by just doing  `$(this).attr('data-id')`

Comment: I'll see if I can modify your code to do it this way.  Give me a few moments..  Oh, before I do could you revert the code-snippet to the one with the challenges in so that it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your click function `$('[id^=challenge_progress]').on('click', function() { // your code }` with below function.

```
$(document).on('click','[id^=challenge_progress]',function(){
  this_id = $(this).attr('id');
  this_id = parseInt(this_id.substr(18, 19));
  challenges.finished.push(challenges.now[this_id]);
  random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * challenges.names.length) + 1);
  while ($.inArray(random_number, challenges.now) != -1 && $.inArray(random_number, challenges.finished) != -1) {
      random_number = Math.floor((Math.random() * challenges.names.length) + 1);
  } 
  $('.CPI_challenge' + this_id + 'o' + challenges.now[this_id]).remove()
  challenges.now[this_id] = random_number;
  addChallenge(this_id)
})
```

Comment: well spotted, for some reason I was thinking his code was using a delegated event..

Comment: works smooth! Except for one problem when there's an undefined result in some tries.

Comment: anyways I wish you can help with one more issue I saw. The challenges are repetitive and seems like the condition that I put in the while loop isn't working.

Comment: there is a error with `challenges` in the above code, can you show me working code so , i can help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I added the code to the snippet, and if it helps it alerts the value of challenges.finished each time you change a challenge. (note: I haven't copied all the CSS code)

Comment: i just check the for loop , i fetch this result in challange.now : 0,35,37,27

Comment: and... btw when the random number worths 1 the details are undefined

Comment: @ofek3103s, check this fiddle , https://jsfiddle.net/g8wca1kx/ , i just put random_number = 1  , so it is always go to the while condition.

Comment: works well! Thank you SOO much for your help! You don't how much I'm happy right now!

Comment: @ofek3103s , check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g8wca1kx/1/  ,  in this you will never get a `undefined`

Comment: nvm this issue still exists... although I changed the condition in the loop to be  while ($.inArray(random_number, challenges.now) != -1 && $.inArray(random_number, challenges.finished) == -1) and it's even getting worse (same challenge after the exact same one)

Comment: yes , when your random number value object is not match in array then this issue is occur. Like random_number = 48 then it is not found in your array and it is displaying a undefined.